Is it irrational to assign a probability to a metaphysical proposition?
One of the responses to Pascal’s Wager is that it may be meaningless to assign a probability to a certain metaphysical proposition such as God’s existence.
In this post about the assignment of probability with respect to metaphysical realities, @Conifold comments,

The assignment is of course meaningless, along with "more", "less", "many other", etc., applied to something as vague as "metaphysical possibilities". See Bertrand paradox for a simple illustration of how probability values depend on arranging "possibilities" into a sample space. Even if one was willing to accept the "base assumption" of equiprobability it is impossible to make sense of what that means here.

Suppose that you are a person who thinks that it is meaningless to assign a probability to God’s existence or that you think the probability of God’s existence is unknown given the lack of experience with any supernatural entities.
Now, in the interpretation of subjective probability, which is often linked to Bayesian thinking, probability is defined as a degree of belief as such:

Your degree of belief in E is p iff p units of utility is the price at which you would buy or sell a bet that pays 1 unit of utility if E, 0 if not E

The neat thing about this definition is that it defines probability in a practical way, in the form of a bet.
Now imagine that this bet is somehow forced upon you, either by the government, or by punishment in such a way where you have no choice but to take this bet. Now, a person who is forced to take this bet where he can only pick between 0 and 1 units, must still take an action (or else, he may be murdered for example).
But if he does pick a number of units (think of this as real money), which he must, does this not mean that he undeniably has a credence in the proposition (which can be translated into a probability) even if he claims not to, making him inconsistent?
Note that if the terms of this bet still seem unrealistic, you can waive these concerns by not thinking of the bet too literally:

These problems stem largely from taking literally the notion of entering into a bet on E, with its corresponding payoffs. The problems may be avoided by identifying your degree of belief in a proposition with the betting price you regard as fair, whether or not you enter into such a bet; it corresponds to the betting odds that you believe confer no advantage or disadvantage to either side of the bet (Howson and Urbach 1993). At your fair price, you should be indifferent between taking either side.


Disclaimer: I am not myself a Bayesian and don’t know on which side of the fence I belong here yet (unless, of course, I was forced to bet on it ;))
P.S. to the current downvoters, explain the downvotes instead of being cowardly, especially since answers by prominent posters have already been given, giving at least some level of indication that they thought the question was worth responding to. This site unfortunately has a wonky history of downvoting/closing things without explanation which is sometimes a sign that there’s no basis for them except a dislike of users.

One potential response I can think of (to my own post) is that a bet under fear may not accurately reflect your belief upon a matter. At the same time, a bet is still an action and a behaviour, and belief is often defined in terms of dispositions

From the SEP "Often cited is the disposition to assent to utterances of P in the right sorts of circumstances". What makes you think a death or life threat is the right sorts of circumstances?

@tkruse “put your money where your mouth is” may indicate your actual belief in something given that you now have a consequence for being wrong. Death may be the ultimate “put your money where your mouth is” where the consequence is now your loss of life instead of a loss of money. So if anything, one may even argue that it is a “truer” form of belief than even other bets. The death example in my post was just a particular scenario though. You can replace it with some other consequence that you think is more appropriate

I didn't downvote your post, however, since you deem this site is wonky, then why you don't complain upvotes for your post without explanation comment which is usually a sign that there’s no basis for them except a like of users?...

Sounds like a Trolley Problem. Heaven and Hell are the original model for all that.

@DoubleKnot Also, in society, and for the purposes of this site, criticism usually requires more of an explanation than something being liked (which is why explanations are attached to close votes). Otherwise, how will we learn and how will one know if criticism has basis to it?

Maybe this is how many forms of societal and epistemic biases came from?...

How do you force someone to place a realistic bet? If you force me to place a bet, why can't my response be to pick a figure at random?

So, at 0 units, nothing happens? Why would not everyone say 0, regardless of belief?

@kutschkem you win money if you’re right

@syed: Not everyone needs the money that you are able to offer them. Everyone is going to evaluate the odds individually and idiosyncratically, and decide whether the potential value of the prize is higher than what they are being asked to invest in order to buy into the game; if it isn't, the winning move is not to play. If there is no cost to enter the game, those not philosophically opposed to it may well pick randomly if they don't have reason to do otherwise. Not deciding IS a legitimate decision, despite your game's attempt to forbid it. If you insist, call that exactly 50% confidence.

For something that appears to be false, I'd simply assign a 0 probability.
As someone who doesn't use probabilistic epistemology for things for which we have no reasonable probability estimates, all such things would either have a 0 or 1 probability (or I might refrain from assigning one of those values if I just don't know).
But I'd have a non-zero confidence about those values, and that confidence increases or decreases based on how sure I am that it's true or false (although I don't have a means of putting a concrete percentage value on that).
This addition of confidence may not, strictly speaking, make it that much different than pure probability. But one key difference is that confidence values don't need to add up to 1. That may sound minor, but it's actually rather significant.
I don't need to consider every* one of the infinitely-many conceivable possibilities to try to come up with some relative percentage for each. And that's just for all possible gods. I might also need to consider all of the countless other implausible-but-not-impossible things to consider whether my time might be better spent on those instead of a god.
Rather than doing all of the above, I can instead just evaluate the evidence until I get to a point of high confidence (not a percentage value) about 1 particular claim, then reject further investigation or commitment as a waste of time, and spend my time on more productive things.
* Proponents of Pascal's wager tend to take for granted that their religion (and more specifically, their particular interpretation of it) stands head-and-shoulders above every other religion (in terms of plausibility). But this would also be a claim an atheist may not accept.

There is nothing inconsistent, or even irrational, about declining to assign a probability to a given proposition. Doing so just amounts to suspending belief or disbelief. Sometimes we wish to say we don't have any idea whether some proposition is true or not and that's all.
I might be compelled to take a bet on a proposition and assign a probability to it when I have little or no evidence to go on. But in the case of propositions such as whether gods exist, I don't see how that would work. How will the party compelling me to bet determine whether I have won or lost? For Pascal, the bet is entirely personal and there is no counterparty. I win or lose depending on whether I discover that my soul has survived death and I am to be rewarded or punished in the afterlife.

I think you’re focusing on the logistics of the bet too much. Pascal’s wager is still ultimately a bet: if you are wrong, you go to hell. If you are right, you go to heaven. If you don’t believe in Pascal’s god, you are ultimately betting against his existence. Thus, at the very least you are betting less than 0.5 units for a bet that pays off 1 unit, if the 1 unit can be represented as heaven.

Pascal's wager has been deconstructed previously. I don't see much point in rehashing the reasons that it doesn't work unless you accept its premises.

I'm not sure we can say that in a forced decision the person has credence toward different outcomes. For example, they may decide to ask their interrogator-executioner their last name -- if it has an even number of letters they pick Yes, otherwise No.
Or they may think that No is safer in that if they are right, they live, if they are wrong, they still live in the afterlife (and maybe try to do a little last minute repenting/groveling to St. Peter ;-)
We can't say they are deciding based on credence unless they are picking based on which they truly feel is the most correct. They may feel they have no idea and choose some arbitrary method to get that person an answer.
I guess a potential loophole is that I can refuse to answer since you didn't specify a timeframe in which I need to make that decision -- maybe I can say "Ok, I promise to decide -- I'll return in 80 years with my definitive answer". I'm guessing they'd say, no, decide in the next 5 seconds or you will die. Given certain death, you're better off guessing somehow.

And if they open one of three doors and you see a goat, change your answer :-)

@ScottRowe -- that would be a fun twist Diabolical Monty Hall

“ We can't say they are deciding based on credence unless they are picking based on which they truly feel is the most correct.” If the punishment for being wrong is death, why wouldn’t they pick what they feel is most correct?

@Syed -- you mentioned that they are someone who denies the validity of assigning a probability to god's existence; therefore, they don't think it's valid to have a feeling about it-  yet they are forced to make a decision so they pick some agnostic/irrelevant method -- its pure pragmatism. Not saying that is how I would do it, but since this is a though experiment I am able to make this claim.

@Annika but why would they pick an irrelevant method if they’re losing money? How many dollars out of 100 for example would you be willing to lose betting on the existence of god if in this hypothetical, if you are right, you win 100, and gain nothing if you’re wrong?

@Syed -- why are you talking about money? I thought the cost of error was death? Again, our hypothetical person thinks the "probability of God" is meaningless or inscrutable, so they are picking a method that matches their belief.

@Annika Death is the consequence for not making the bet: i.e. you’re forced to make a bet. The consequence would still just be losing money. I mentioned death as a consequence of losing the bet earlier but changed that because that would correspond better to a binary bet. In this case, I am trying to see if belief can be represented as degrees by thinking of a bet like that

@Syed Gotcha -- I must have been responding to an older version. But you are implicitly assuming what you are trying to prove -- that the the only way they can make a decision is via credence, but that isn't logically necessary -- I gave alternatives that are effectively "arational" (even irrational) -- which actually are rational if the person doesn't think that "Probability of God" has any meaning (note: not 50% but literally P(God) = NaN)

@Annika suppose a person has 100 dollars. It makes no sense for him to then choose a random method for this bet unless he does not care about losing his money whatever.

@Syed - I'm having a hard time understanding the betting thing here. If I didn't care about this bet, why wouldn't I just bet $0 cause I want to get this over with and guarantee I won't lose money (i.e., I'm horribly loss averse).

@Annika that’s a great point and your concerns are part of why I’m not sure if the Bayesian degree of belief concept can be mapped onto bets accurately. However, there are responses here that deal with what you just said: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/#SubPro. Essentially, you can just answer the question: “if this was part of a betting book, what do I think the fair value would be?”

@Syed the issue is that I may think it’s an ill conceived bet overall — like “the ratio of leprechauns to unicorns is > 1” - but I’m faced with choosing nonetheless— I’d just use a random number generator to get out of dying

@Annika well, in the case just mentioned, you are trying to decide the fair price of a betting book. So you don’t have to make the bet. For me, personally, for example, since there’s no evidence for leprechauns or unicorns, the fair price of this bet or odds should be an extremely high number to 1.

@Syed why so high a price? And I thought we were forced to bet?

@Annika odds, not price. In other words, I think a fair reward for betting on your example would be huge compared to the cost. And I’m talking about my last comment. See the quote, since I realize that us personally betting results in issues

“These problems stem largely from taking literally the notion of entering into a bet on E, with its corresponding payoffs. The problems may be avoided by identifying your degree of belief in a proposition with the betting price you regard as fair, whether or not you enter into such a bet; it corresponds to the betting odds that you believe confer no advantage or disadvantage to either side of the bet (Howson and Urbach 1993). At your fair price, you should be indifferent between taking either side”

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The basis of your question is unrealistic to the point of being meaningless.   How can you place a bet on the probability of an unprovable proposition, since by definition you have know way of knowing whether your bet is correct?
However, leaving that aside, your question seems to be about whether a person, for whatever reason, assigning a probability to some unprovable notion is in some way expressing a degree of credence. I think your question is tautologous. If I say I am convinced god exists, I will naturally assign a probability of 1. If I am convinced god does not exist, I will assign a probability of zero. In other words, posing the question 'what do you believe to be the probability of x?' seems to me to be no different to the question 'how strongly do you believe x' where x is some entirely unprovable notion for which there is no logical way to quantify probability.


But if he does pick one, which he must, does this not mean that he undeniably has a credence in the proposition (which can be translated into a probability) even if he claims not to, making him inconsistent?

Suppose it is objectively true that individual X subconsciously assigns probability P to proposition Y. How can this be? Where, within the mind of X, can this probability P be said to reside? What does it even mean for this probability P to exist?
If physicalism is true, the statement "individual X assigns probability P to proposition Y" must ultimately reduce to concrete physical facts (see the related discussion: How does physicalism interpret mathematical theorems in physicalist terms?). So, what physical facts would correspond to a probability? How are propositions represented in the brain, and how are beliefs about those propositions stored? Are neurons physically encoding a "probability" for each proposition? Does the brain compute probabilities, and if so, is this an accurate model of how the brain works?  (Interesting article: Are our brains Bayesian?)
I’m willing to grant that the individual likely has some belief about proposition Y, but I wouldn’t immediately leap to the conclusion that "it can be translated into a probability." If physicalism is true, I’m unsure how one could substantiate such a claim.
Even under alternative metaphysical views, such as dualism, it’s not clear how one could establish that probability P must exist within a spiritual or immaterial mind.

If the probability P is some level of money you would bet on given a particular kind of bet, it doesn’t need to be stored anywhere in the brain. The same way you moving your hand given me burning it doesn’t imply that this scenario is physically stored in your brain.

@Syed If determinism is true, then there is no probability, just a fixed action I would do given a fixed set of conditions. If indeterminism is true and there are objective probabilities governing random events in the universe, then there might be a probability that I will choose action X under circumstances C.

degree of belief is an epistemic probability, not an objective one

@Syed Again, epistemic probabilities either exist or don't exist. If physicalism is true, they  would need to exist physically. If they are not a physical state in the brain, where else would they exist?

They would exist in the bets that you take that are part of the physical world @user802276

"If physicalism is true" - do you hold that physicalism is true? If not... why are you focusing on that (with only a single sentence dedicated to all alternatives)? The question doesn't mention it. Also, numbers might be one of the easiest things to represent and work with with physical systems (depends on the physical system, of course). The question of how physical systems create experiences is much harder (but I'd say consciousness reducing to the brain is still the best explanation for that that we have).

@NotThatGuy https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/120516/80226


Now imagine that this bet is somehow forced upon you, either by the government, or by punishment in such a way where you have no choice but to take this bet.

By ignoring the group of individuals, who given a choice between "bet or die", choose die. You are effectively cherry-picking your data. Any answer to a question based on a fallacy is tainted. For example:
By a highly improbable event (miracle) one of the players who chose "die" doesn't die and escapes.
This escapee organizes and leads underground movement to destroy this vile bet and give all the freedom of choice.
He wins and the sinister bet is illuminated and never used again.
How does this scenario factor in your betting scheme?
If out of 100 players only 3 bet and the rest chose death. How does that impact the relevance of your bet?
Finally, your assumption that the threat of death will lead to a bet choice 100% of time is a hasty generalization based on your personal bias.
