Do epistemic probabilities exist?
There are many questions on this site about subjective probabilities, epistemic probabilities, assigning probabilities/credences to hypotheses, bayesian reasoning, etc. The following are just a few examples:

Are epistemic probability and empirical probability comparable?
Can objective epistemic probabilistic comparisons be established between metaphysical worldviews?
Can probability amplitudes be used as credences?
Is it irrational to assign a probability to a metaphysical proposition?
How does one argue for the rationality of assigning subjective probabilities in the context of Pascal’s Wager?
Is it valid to calculate the probability of different metaphysical realities?
Does a 100% degree of belief imply that no amount of evidence can change your mind?
Does the Bayesian degree of belief system result in absurd conclusions?

If epistemic probabilities are real, they must exist somewhere. Under physicalism, they would presumably have to correspond to physical states in the brain. Even under alternative metaphysical views, such as dualism, epistemic probabilities would still require some kind of physical counterpart—unless they are somehow stored in the "spiritual" or "immaterial mind."
Do epistemic probabilities exist?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I think this question is yet another one based on different interpretations of the word "exist".
If these probabilities are ideas and interpretations, they exist in the same way, and to the same degree, that other ideas and interpretations do.
Yes, a physicalist would say that these reside in the brain, and that we are still learning where and exactly how they are stored and processed.
If you insist on putting them elsewhere, you will have to explain how they interact with the body, and why intoxication of or damage to the brain can inhibit ability to access and manipulate them. I submit that this is no easier then explaining the mind as the state of the brain, and to me it seems harder.
Note: as always, this is based on my own understanding of physicalism. I am not going to do a full literature search on the question; I simply don't feel that much need to defend it. I am merely indicating that the appearance of contradiction only exists if you start by rejecting physicalism.

"If you insist on putting them elsewhere" - You can also put them nowhere (i.e., reject their existence).

@user80226: Certainly, if that's your preferred answer. "Mu."

@shindemo: Please reread; I didn't say that. I specifically gave a physicalist response. Non-physicalists will, of course, believe differently. Which I admit I find confusing, but interesting.

Not all anything believe anything; reality is fractal, fuzzy, and shades of grey. My understanding is that the predominant physicalist view is that abstract objects are like any other concept, a model we carry in our heads, rather than having some kind of independent existence. As I've said elsewhere, if we can imagine a plaid elephant, we can imagine a perfect sphere, despite neither having independent existence. But as with any belief system, there are going to be people who draw the lines somewhat differently but still group themselves under the same label though others may not agree.
